# Is there a cleaner and more efficient way to make these BMI & Fat% calculators in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm new to python (and coding in general & SOF). I recently picked it up after going through some online HTML, CSS tracks on Treehouse and really enjoy it until now. Apart from the hobby aspect my general bigger goal is to be able to write my own web applications/programs related to my field of work & study (healthcare).

So.. My question is related to this piece of code I wrote today. It's a general BMI calculator and also includes a fatpercentage estimator (based on a few variables that need to be provided). It's by no means a 100% accurate fat% calculator (you'd need a DXA-scan to get a better idea), although it works fine for the general public.

**Questions:**

1) How do I make sure that a user can input multiple things into the height prompt? Some users might want to add 187 and others will put in 1.87. How do I account for this and make sure the calculator still works?

2) Do I need to write all those print statements in my functions or is there a cleaner/better way to write these functions?

3) If I want the user to be able to select the imperial or metric system? How do I do this and do I need to make 2 extra functions for these?

Thanks in advance and here is the code (ps. don't mind the "strange" print messages :) ):

```
# BMI calculator & fatpercentage estimator

#VARS

gender = input("What is your gender? Male or female? ")
age = input("How old are you? ")
length = float(input("What is your length in meters? Input should be: 1.80 for example. "))
weight = int(input("How much do you weigh (in KG)? "))
userinput_fatpercentage = int(input("What is your fatpercentage?\nReturn 0 (zero) if you don't know and want to calculate. "))
bmi = round(weight/(length*length), 2)

# BMI CALC

def bmi_calulation():
    if bmi <= 18.5:
        print("Your Body Mass Index is:", bmi, "start eating, skinny.")
    elif bmi > 18.5 and bmi < 25:
        print("Your Body Mass Index (BMI) is: ", bmi, "you are a normal person, thank god.")
    elif bmi > 25 and bmi < 30:
        print("Your Body Mass Index (BMI) is: ", bmi, "mind you... You are overweight. Drop some weight.")
    elif bmi > 30:
        print("Your Body Mass Index (BMI) is: ", bmi, "Hnnngggg..! You are insanely overweight. Stop eating right away!")
    else:
        print("There was an error with your input. Try again.")

# FAT% ESTIMATOR

def fatpercentage_calculation():
    if userinput_fatpercentage == 0 and gender.lower() == 'male':
        print("Your fatpercentage is: ")
        print(round((1.2 * float(bmi) + (0.23 * float(age) - (10.8 * 1) - 5.4)), 2))
    elif userinput_fatpercentage == 0 and gender.lower() == 'female':
        print("Your fatpercentage is: ")
        print(round((1.2 * float(bmi) + (0.23 * float(age) - (10.8 * 0) - 5.4)), 2))
    elif userinput_fatpercentage == userinput_fatpercentage:
        print("Your fatpercentage is: {}.".format(userinput_fatpercentage))
    else:
        print("Something went wrong. Try again. ")

#Output

bmi_calulation()
fatpercentage_calculation()
```

Comment: Hint: this question looks like it should probably be on [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: If the code works, which you haven't mentioned it not, I'd definitely head over to Code Review as suggested

Comment: Ah thanks, didn't know that option was available.

Comment: Side note on your wording. It might be better to say "start eating, skinny b\*tch" instead of "start eating skinny bitch" which might be read as "start eating skinny, b*tch" where it sounds like you're using _skinny_ as an adverb.

Comment: You can extract the exact code from this https://bmiwiki.com/bmi-calculator/ and edit it as per your need. Quite easy to play with simply html and js.

Answer (score 2):

1) You don't have to worry about inputs 1.87 vs 187 since you specified the format in the prompt as meters. It would be the user's fault if they put in cm in this case. Another design would be to ask the user before the height question whether they would want to use meters or cm, let them choose, and then internally in your code only use one (convert if they chose the other).

2) The parts that are repeating you can print before the if statements, and then print the details inside the if statements based on the case. If you don't want newlines between the two parts, you can use

```
print('.', end='')
```

to print without creating a newline.

3) Again, you can simply prompt the user for this. To avoid writing 2 similar codes to account for 2 systems, you can internally convert the user choice into one of them, and calculate everything (then you can convert back for printing).

Comment: Thanks a lot! Surely helps!